# How to combine two different dates in PHP

Tags: php, date

I need to combine this two:

```
<?= helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->start, 'format' => 'l, j. F Y, H:i','timezone'=>'UTC' )); ?> - <?= helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->end, 'format' => 'H:i','timezone'=>'UTC')); ?>
```

to be only one PHP line. How can I accomplish this?
The Output of this two lines is:

```
Sonntag, 7. Januar 2018, 19:30 - 20:40
```

I tried something like this:

```
<?= 
helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' -> $event->start, 'format' -> 'l, j. F Y, H:i' . "-" . -> $event->end, 'format' -> 'H:i','timezone'=>'UTC')); 
?>
```

Comment: How we supposed to know what is `helper()` and how it works?

Comment: @Tanu I tried something like this:  `<?= helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' -> $event->start, 'format' -> 'l, j. F Y, H:i' . "-" . -> $event->end, 'format' -> 'H:i','timezone'=>'UTC')); ?>` but it doesn't work.

Comment: If I had to guess, your `helper` function won't be able to format two separate timestamps in a single call. But it's impossible for us to say without the source of the function.

Comment: @ArtOsi the `helper()` calls the dynamically generated date. What I need to do is just combine this two into one.

Comment: `->` looks wrong, should that not be `=>`

Comment: Try adding [error reporting](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/845021/how-to-get-useful-error-messages-in-php/845025#845025) to the
top of your file(s) _while testing_ right after your opening PHP tag for example
`<?php error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', 1);` to see if it yields anything.

Comment: @RiggsFolly `syntax error, unexpected ''l, j. F Y, H:i'' (T_CONSTANT_ENCAPSED_STRING), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or '{' or '$`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution is this:

```
<?= helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->start, 'format' => 'l, j. F Y, H:i','timezone'=>'UTC')), ' - ', helper('com://site/ohanah.date.format', array('date' => $event->end, 'format' => 'H:i', 'timezone'=>'UTC')); ?>
```